# Which jQuery plugin can search elements and show them in a DIV in realtime?

Tags: jquery, html, search, plugins, navigation

I am searching for a jQuery plugin that would allow me to:

1. Have input that would be used for user search text
2. Search through my elements

   Show all  elements that fit the search string from the first input. So like a search system through elements, but I need to show these elements in some other DIV.

I am using quick search currently (https://github.com/riklomas/quicksearch)
It works VERY good, I just have one problem:

My navigation looks like that:

```
<div class="nav-column">
<h3>Š</h3>
<ul class="submenu">
<li><a href="">
Šentjur <small>(2)</small></a></li>
<li><a href="">
Šmarje <small>(2)</small></a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

And then I use quicksearch like this:

```
$(".navigationHolder").quicksearch("ul li");
```

Which works like charm, except that of course h3 element is always staying there and I get this:
[image: Problem with jQuery plugin]

Comment: learn to code instead of using plugins

Comment: Is there any event bound to the search function ? If yes, i guess you just have to hide/show any h3 element according to the shown elements when that event is tirggered.

Comment: Yeah use that option: `#### onAfter Function to call after trigger is called`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`#### onAfter Function to call after trigger is called`

Using that option you should be able to achieve your goal. The funciton should look like this.

```
function(){
  $('h3').each(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    //selecting all visible li elements associated to the title
    var $li = $this.next('.submenu').find('li:visible');

    //hiding or showing h3
    if($li.length>0)
       $this.show();
    else
       $this.hide();
  });
}
```

You can probably work with the `div class='nav-column'`, if there is one div per letter.